# How can I display page in I frame from div with specific ID?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work on my Angularjs project. I use `iframe` in my project to display some page.

here is iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" ng-`src="../playground/#/sitesDamages" ></iframe>:`
```

Here is div that I want to display in template displayed in Iframe:

```
<div id="frameArea">
  //some content
</div>
```

The problem that I want the page to be displayed from specific div where `Id="frameArea"`.

Comment: Post your HTML template.

Comment: Approach sounds wrong already.... should be implementing it from data in your model not from an element id. Without any code you won't get any help. See [mcve]

Comment: why would you want to use an iframe to display content from the same site?

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, you could just use a simple  and use the jQuery "load" function to load the whole page and pluck out just the section you want:

```
$('#target-div').load('http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolio.php #portfolio-sports');
```

Comment: could you please provide more specific example?Where do I call this JQUERY?

Comment: this may work, but it's counter to the design principles of angular, and it's not necessarily a good idea to introduce bad coding habits like this without knowing the actual intended result.  especially given the OP doesn't even seem to know what the jQuery library is...

Comment: @Michael you can use this code (but with your parameters) in any place of your code.

Comment: can it be used in ng-init in iframe?